# How to i make rectangle move across the screen processing js

Tags: processing.js

I want to make the white rectangles move across the screen like traffic and stop when the light is red. I have started this on the move method, totally new to processing js.
Currently the cars are the correct distance apart but i am unsure how to move thtis loop and move across the screen until the traiff light is red.

```java
let counter = 0;
let lightorder = 0;

//setup the enviroment i.e. roads, lines on roads and trees
void setup() {

size(1330, 720);
background(96, 153, 25);

//Roads

noStroke();
fill(100);
rect(0, 200 + 10, 1330, 300);
rect(520, 0, 300, 1500);


//Lines on road

fill(255);
rect(0, 340, 90, 30);

rect(200, 340, 90, 30);
rect(400, 340, 90, 30);
rect(860, 340, 90, 30);
rect(1060, 340, 90, 30);
rect(1260, 340, 90, 30);
rect(655, 75, 30, 90);
rect(655, 575, 30, 90);

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
      move(i = i +20)
}

}


//work out light order and assign and fill shapes on traffic lights according
void draw() {



determineLightOrder();
trafficLight();
trafficLight2();
trafficLight3();
trafficLight4();

}

void move(int p){
rect(p, 230, 200, 70);
rect(p, 400, 200, 70);
}



//determine if traffic light is red, yellow or green and fill shape 
accordingly
void trafficLight() {

let is_red_light = lightorder == 2;
let is_yellow_light = lightorder == 1;
let is_green_light = lightorder == 0;

stroke(250);
fill(0);
rect(10 + 550, 10 + 80, 40, 100);

if (is_red_light) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
}
else {
    fill(100);
}

ellipse(30 + 550, 30 + 80, 20, 20);

if (is_yellow_light) {
    fill(250, 250, 0);
    ellipse(30 + 550, 60 + 80, 20, 20);
}

// green ligh

if (is_green_light) {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    ellipse(30 + 550, 90 + 80, 20, 20);

}

}

 void trafficLight2() {

//declare light color variables 
let is_red_light = lightorder == 0;
let is_yellow_light = lightorder == 2;
let is_green_light = lightorder == 1;

stroke(250);
fill(0);
rect(10 + 850, 10 + 215, 40, 100);

if (is_red_light) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
}
else {
    fill(100);
}

ellipse(30 + 850, 30 + 215, 20, 20);

if (is_yellow_light) {
    fill(250, 250, 0);
    ellipse(30 + 850, 60 + 215, 20, 20);
}


if (is_green_light) {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    ellipse(30 + 850, 90 + 215, 20, 20);
}

}

//same code as the trafficLight2 different position of lights
void trafficLight3() {

stroke(250);
fill(0);
rect(10 + 420, 10 + 380, 40, 100);

let is_red_light = lightorder == 0;
let is_yellow_light = lightorder == 2;
let is_green_light = lightorder == 1;

if (is_red_light) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
}
else {
    fill(100);
}

ellipse(30 + 420, 30 + 380, 20, 20);

if (is_yellow_light) {
    fill(250, 250, 0);
    ellipse(30 + 420, 60 + 380, 20, 20);
}


if (is_green_light) {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    ellipse(30 + 420, 90 + 380, 20, 20);
}

}

 //same code as trafficLight1 different position of lights
 void trafficLight4() {

let is_red_light = lightorder == 2;
let is_yellow_light = lightorder == 1;
let is_green_light = lightorder == 0;

stroke(250);
fill(0);
rect(10 + 730, 10 + 525, 40, 100);

if (is_red_light) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
}
else {
    fill(100);
}

ellipse(30 + 730, 30 + 525, 20, 20);

if (is_yellow_light) {
    fill(250, 250, 0);
    ellipse(30 + 730, 60 + 525, 20, 20);
}


if (is_green_light) {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    ellipse(30 + 730, 90 + 525, 20, 20);
}


}

//determine the light order
void determineLightOrder() {

counter++;

if (counter == 200) {
    counter = 0;
    lightorder = 0;
}
else if (counter == 50) {
    lightorder = 1;
}
else if (counter == 70) {
    lightorder = 2;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

I wrote [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) on animation in Processing that I highly recommend you read. But basically, you need to store the state of your program (for example, the position of the rectangles) in a variable (or multiple variables). Use those variables to draw your scene, and then change those variables over time to create an animation.

[Break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those pieces on one at a time. Can you create a simple program that shows a single moving square? Then get that square to stop given a certain criteria. Then add a second square. Keep working your way forward in small steps like that, and if you get stuck on a specific step, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific question. Good luck.